# NRI Son's Remittance Transferred to Indian Parents

Tags: investing, india

My son is an NRI (Non-resident Indian) working in the US. He sends money to his NRE (Non-resident External) a/c.Then the money is transferred to the Indian parents ac. Is there any restriction on parents in investing such money in immovable properties?

Comment: I dont think so, because IIRC, this will be treated as a gift to the parents, and they can use it anyway they like.

Answer (score 1):

The money you receive from son would be treated as gift. As per gift tax you can get unlimited money from son and there is no tax implication. You are free to use money as you like. There is no restriction. Any profit you make is taxable as income to you.